# gVim on Windows: imap does not map ç (cedilla) when read from _vimrc

Tags: vim

Weird issue here: I'm trying to avoid the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to exit from insert mode. I stumbled upon this article: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key and I liked the following solution:

```
" Two letters.
:imap çç <Esc>
```

When in gVim I type:

```
:imap çç <Esc>
```

I *does* work. But when I try to make it default by putting it in my _vimrc file:

```
imap çç <ESC>
```

I doesn't work. It gives me no error, but does not work. Every other letter works, but it seems that specifically the letter `ç` doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write :

```
au VimEnter * imap çç <ESC>
```

in your .vimrc . `au` is short of `autocmd` and it is used to tell vim that you want to execute this one as a semicolon command. `VimEnter` is telling vim to execute it on startup. 
The syntax is :

```
autocmd events pattern command
```

You could also see the help for `autocmd`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following:

1. Add

   ```
   scriptencoding utf-8
   set encoding=utf-8
   ```

   at the very beginning of your vimrc.
2. Be sure that vimrc is saved in UTF-8 itself.

Comment: It did not work for me. Even if it did, I wouldn't be sure because almost all my files are encoded latin-1. I don't know if theres anything to do with it. The strange thing is that Slavchev's solution only worked after I removed those two lines you asked me to add. But I'm pretty sure it did not work because I did not get it right. Thanks for taking the time. Appreciate it!

Comment: @aldux You should have had another problem: all latin1 accented characters are the same as `<A-key>` (a hello from 7-bit terminals). If it got remapped in some plugin, it won’t work in the vimrc no matter what encoding is and it is rather tricky to guess the interfering map. I assumed your problem was encoding. @DimitarSlavchev assumed your problem was interfering mapping (or at least, I assume he did): VimEnter event is fired after all plugins were loaded.

Comment: And I also have all-UTF-8 setup (except for some files, they do not matter). I may have forgotten something because of that: 'encoding', 'termencoding' (actually empty, but that uses 'encoding') and what terminal is actually sending to vim is all UTF-8 on my system. Maybe that was the problem: if terminal sends something different from string in 'encoding' you must tweak 'termencoding' as well. Talking about terminal here because all GUIs have known encoding and either ignore 'termencoding' or force it to a constant value.

Comment: @ZyX I assumed nothing. Actually I was first thinking that imap wouldn't work in .vimrc, then I realised I was wrong. I am glad that it worked.